# How to select rows and columns from a file?

Tags: python, file, numpy

In Python 3.5, I need to select -from a file that has 16,000 rows and 1000 columns- only certain values that meet a given criteria. Can I use numpy - with conditionals - to select based on indeces?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the File, assign a variable then apply a filter.

1. `df=File` Import (e.g. `df=pd.read_csv(...)`)
2. define a criteria `columnX>5000`
3. Filter: `df[df.columnX>5000]`

The output will be a dataframe filtered by your criteria